# Python 3 argparse: how to accept all float values and a list of strings in one positional argument?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Without describing what my program really do, let me tell a fake use case, which should be enough to demonstrate my intended argument usage.

Let's say I'm building an alarm program (again, this is a fake use case, so please don't start telling me we have native alarms in Linux/Windows). It can alarm at both certain predefined time (e.g. "morning", "noon") and after given amount of minutes. I want my command to accept these use cases:

```
$ python alarm_at.py morning
$ python alarm_at.py noon
$ python alarm_at.py evening
$ python alarm_at.py 1
$ python alarm_at.py 2
$ python alarm_at.py 3
...
```

The constraint is that I only want to use one positional argument for this purpose. Also, there might be other positional arguments which I need, so something like this should be allowed:

```
$ python alarm_at.py loud morning long
$ python alarm_at.py low 3 short
```

In the above, I have two imaginary positional arguments designated for the loudness and the length of the alarm sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) you will find this:

> type= can take any callable that takes a single string argument and returns the converted value

```
>>> def perfect_square(string):
...     value = int(string)
...     sqrt = math.sqrt(value)
...     if sqrt != int(sqrt):
...         msg = "%r is not a perfect square" % string
...         raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
...     return value
...
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('foo', type=perfect_square)
>>> parser.parse_args(['9'])
Namespace(foo=9)
>>> parser.parse_args(['7'])
usage: PROG [-h] foo
PROG: error: argument foo: '7' is not a perfect square
```

So you can create a function that accepts the values you want and set it as the argument type.
It doesn't matter how many positional arguments you have just set them in the right order and `required` or not.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to know. And the code snippet helps a lot. To summarize, we can use `ArgumentTypeError` to reject invalid values, and even do some transformation in the function.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you ;-)

Comment: Thank you a lot, epinal. :)   Also, I didn't know the "%r" notation, which will be very helpful in creating error messages where we want to quote values. So, two thumbs-up for you.